# finding the loss derivative w.r.t. weights for a convolutional layer

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, softmax, cross-entropy

Take the loss function:
$$
\mathrm{loss}
~~=~~
\sum_{i=1}^N \left( -z_{}[y] + \log{\left( \sum_{c=1}^{10} \exp(z_{}[c]) \right)} \right)$$
where $z \in \mathbb{R}^{10}$ is the input to the softmax layer and $z{[c]}$ denotes the $c$-th entry of vector $z$.

I'm trying to find $$\frac{\partial loss}{\partial W}\quad \frac{\partial loss}{\partial x}, \quad \text{where } x \text{ is as 4d tensor}$$. Under the assumption that we have a filter of size (HXWXD) and stride 1. Would be really appreciative if somebody could detail this for me as I have been stuck for a while.

Thanks.

Comment: I meant $$
\mathrm{loss}
~~=~~
-z_{}[y] + \log{\left( \sum_{c=1}^{10} \exp(z_{}[c]) \right)}$$
where $z \in \mathbb{R}^{10}$ is the input to the softmax layer and $z{[c]}$ denotes the $c$-th entry of vector $z$.

Comment: You can find a very clear description on how to obtain deltas and errors for CNNs [on the blog of Andrew Gibiansky](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/machine-learning/convolutional-neural-networks/):

Comment: You want the derivative of the loss with respect to the width of the image? That makes no sense